# Rails Workflow::create_workflow_diagram options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, workflow, graphviz

What are all the options available for the command:

```
Workflow::create_workflow_diagram(klass, dir, opts)
```

and how shall I specify them on Ruby code?

I've already found [this](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html) on graphviz options, but I don't know how to use these options on Ruby code...

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass the options separated by commas as a string:

```
Workflow::create_workflow_diagram(Account, "/tmp/", 'rankdir="LR", size="7,11.6", ratio="fill"')
```

Taken from here: http://yardoc.org/docs/geekq-workflow/Workflow